# Using formula to operate the last sheet of an external workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There are 2 workbooks as below:

A.xlsx and B.xlsx

Thinking about making a formula in the cell $A$1 of A.xlsx to refer to cell $A$1 of the last sheet of B.xlsx, just like the following.

```
='[B.xlsx]lastsheet'!A1
```

It can be done by giving the last sheet of B.xlsx a name called "lastsheet" but it is not flexible when a new sheet is regularly added.

Any solution apart from VBA?

Comment: Are you sure it will **always** be the last sheet in the B.xlsx file? No one is going to change the position of the sheet?

Comment: *Any solution apart from VBA?* As far as I know, there is no way to get the last worksheet of a workbook only with formulas.

Comment: oh - APART from VBA? nevermind then. I missed that part.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns: It is possible to get the last sheet name in the same workbook using a formula. I am not sure about getting it from another workbook though. I guess will have to do some RnD

Comment: Richard, I have a suggestion. You can get the last sheet name in B.Xlsx using a formula and save it say in some prdefined cell. Simply refer to that cell to get the name?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

For this to work

1. File B has to be saved as `.xlsm` as we are using Excel 4 function `GET.WORKBOOK(1)`
2. File B has to be open as we are using `INDIRECT`

**Workbook B Setup**

Open `Formula | Name Manager` and create a new defined name. Say, **GetLastSheetName** and enter the below formula in `Refers To`

```
=RIGHT(GET.WORKBOOK(1),LEN(GET.WORKBOOK(1))-FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)))
```

[image]

Next, in any sheet of your choice, enter the formula

```
=INDEX(GetLastSheetName,COUNTA(GetLastSheetName)+RAND()*0)
```

You will see that the name of the last sheet appears in this cell. For explanation purpose, let's assume that you entered the above formula in `A1` of `Sheet1`

[image]
One last thing. Let's say your last worksheet in B.xlsm is Sheet4 which has a value "1111" in cell `A1`.

[image]

We will try and get this value in `A.xlsx` using `Indirect`

**Workbook A**

Insert this formula in any cell of `A.xlsx`

```
=INDIRECT("[B.xlsm]"&[B.xlsm]Sheet1!$A$1&"!A1")
```

and you will get `1111`. Notice we have not used the name of the last sheet `Sheet4` anywhere. The `[B.xlsm]Sheet1!$A$1` part gets the `Sheet4` and then `Indirect` get the value of `A1` from `Sheet4`

[image]

**Recommendation**

Having said/done all the above, I would recommend using VBA because that would be much more simpler.